# way too long maven url

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I'm following a course that implementes Java EE standards using the Vaadin framework, Maven, Spring Boot and JPA.

I have succesfully deployed my Maven project + modules to a Jboss WildFly Server.

A minor error that is ocurring is: in the course, the application URL is

http://localhost:8080/univers-web/*

but when I compile and run the application I have to type:

http://localhost:8080/univers-web-1.3.6.RELEASE

Is a minor annoyance ,but is there a way to remove the project version from the URL name?

I checked the pom.xml file and here is the starting snippet of code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>univers-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    .
    .
    .

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the **build** section of your pom, add `<finalName>univers-web</finalName>`.

Comment: This will not help cause it's the context root of the application..this is only for `target` directory.